# Alternatives to "inside view"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I want to describe in details how something works. It is good to say:

> "I want to describe it from inside view"

?

If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: You could say "I want to look at it in ***cross-section***", but that has a very literal, physical interpretation. You can also say "I want to ***analyze*** this" (which is derived from "take apart and inspect the pieces"), but that may be too abstract. Can you give a few examples of what you to describe (and what parts or processes of it you'd like to describe)?

Comment: Nevermind, your edit cleared it up for me. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use "in detail" or "in full detail"?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, an "inside view" is clumsy. I would suggest "internal".

> I want to describe it from an internal view.

Comment: That's hardly less clumsy.   “I want to describe it from the inside” is far more natural.

Answer (score 2):

The closest common term for "*inside view*" is "***internal perspective***", as in

> *I want to describe it from an **internal perspective***.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *I want to describe its [inner workings](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inner_workings)*.

> The mechanisms that function internally to a system and are not outwardly visible
>   *Nobody really understands the inner workings of politics.* [*Wiktionary*]